# How can I add a generated htmlwidget to Rmarkdown and convert it to a Word document?

Tags: r-markdown, htmlwidgets

I would like to create a word document of the items in a shiny dashboard. The dashboard contains text, plots generated by ggplot and htmlwidgets.

The generation of the word document is done via Rmarkdown and it goes well when I am including text and the ggplots. I am struggling with htmlwidgets though. I have tried to include the html, generated from the htmlwidget directly into the document, but it doesn't work. It does work when I choose as output "html_document" instead of "word_document". 
Some elements are included but some others seem to be get neglected. Below just a simple example, the link and image are not appearing in the word document. Any ideas?

```
---
title: 'Title'
output: 
  word_document:
    md_extensions: +markdown_in_html_blocks
---

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
<a href="https://google.com"><h2>Text without link</h2></a>
<img src="test.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's a job for the `webshot` package

Comment: This question is very interesting, but the example does not work for the following reason: as explained in [Pandoc's documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-html), raw `HTML` is passed through unchanged in `HTML` and suppressed in other format. Could you provide a best suited example?

Comment: thanks you so much! I have been able to add the image of the htmlwidget to the word document via the webshot package. Yes you are right my example is not working because it is suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it working, thanks to the suggestion of @romles
It's a bit different than my previous example since I am generating the rmarkdown string in R code.

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)
library(canvasXpress)

rpt <- c("---", 
         "title: htmlwidget output", 
         paste("output: ", "  word_document"), 
         "---")

tmp_html <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
tmp_image <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
tmp_md  <-  "out.md"
out_docx <- "out.docx"

data <- t(iris[,1:4])
varAnnot <- as.matrix(iris[,5])
colnames(varAnnot) <- "Species"
widget <- canvasXpress(t(data), 
                       varAnnot = varAnnot, 
                       graphType = 'Scatter3D', 
                       colorBy = 'Species')

saveWidget(widget, tmp_html, selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot(tmp_html, 
        file = tmp_image, 
        vwidth = widget$width, 
        vheight = widget$height)

image_md <- paste0("![](", tmp_image, ")")
rpt <- c(rpt, image_md)

report.md <- knitr::knit(text = rpt, output = tmp_md)
rmarkdown::render(input = tmp_md, 
                  output_format = "word_document",
                  output_file   = out_docx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @ginberg solution can be simplified in a more straightforward way: since `knitr` v1.13, HTML widgets are automatically rendered as snapshots using the `webshot` package.

**Setup**
First, `webshot` and `phantomjs` need to be installed:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

**Automatically convert htmlwidgets**

````
library(magrittr)
library(canvasXpress)
library(rmarkdown)

tmp_rmd <- "out.Rmd"

data <- t(iris[,1:4])
varAnnot <- as.matrix(iris[,5])
colnames(varAnnot) <- "Species"

widget <- canvasXpress(t(data), 
                       varAnnot = varAnnot, 
                       graphType = 'Scatter3D', 
                       colorBy = 'Species')

"---
title: htmlwidget output
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
widget
```
" %>% cat(file = tmp_rmd)

render(tmp_rmd, word_document())
````

Obviously, you can permanently store the `out.Rmd` file to simplify the code.

Comment: thanks, I like your solution, it's definitely more simple.